# Django Model Inheritance - get child

Tags: django

Is there a way to access the actual child of the base model, means: Staying with the example from the django Docs, let's assume I am modeling different delivery restaurants, that just have in common

- name
- all have a `deliver` method

as of this:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Pizzeria(Place):
    topping = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    tip = models.IntegerField()

    def deliver(self):
        deliver_with_topping(self.topping)
        ask_for_tip(self.tip)

class Shoarma(Place):
    sauce = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    meat = models.CharField(max_lenght=10)

    def deliver(self):
        prepare_sauce_with_meat(self.sauce, self.meat)
```

I would now like to execute:

```
Place.objects.get(name="my_place").<GENERIC_CHILD>.deliver()
```

i.e. I don't need to know what the place is actually, just the common `deliver` method. The model then 'knows' what to call.

Is there something like `<GENERIC_CHILD>`?

Comment: I use http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html It works like a charm.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I will accept it as an answer - I suppose it is not covered by django itself if there is an extra package for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use [Inheritance Manager from django-model-utils](http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html) for this kind of operations. On your models:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    objects = InheritanceManager()   #<- add inheritance manager
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def deliver(self):
        pass  #not needed
```

Your query:

```
Place.objects.get_subclass(name="my_place").deliver()
```

For me it is a clean and elegant solution. Don't forget to star-up [django-model-util repo](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils) if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a messy way.
I do have parent class Activity, with childs - Action, Deal, Order classes.
I want to list them all in 1 place, 1) with a field specifieing it's class, 2) link them to same page, where i will render page based on Activity class

So in my model Activity i add:

```
def get_type(self):
    children = ['action', 'deal', 'order']
    for c in children:
        try:
            _ = self.__getattribute__(c) # returns child model
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
        else:
            return c
    else:
        return 'Not specified'
```